# Turn on/off a led in Raspberry pi after a Mysql update

Tags: php, mysql, linux, raspberry-pi, gpio

my project is amolst a timer that should turn on/off some leds when the users specifie. The user acesses a web site, insert the pin-id and time(day and hour) into the mysql table and when a time matches the current(using mysql event) the mysql update the pin-id's state and (somehow) turn on the respective led.
I'm not sure how to make the 'turning on' part, i thought about a cronjob to check every 3  minutes if the table were updated or use mysql event with UDF command. 
What do you think guys?? is there a better way??

Comment: Polling is the only way to go (pretty much, without some really hacky solutions) if you're using MySQL as your primary source for changes. You could consider creating an api that the rasberry pi exposes, that you can call from your application for near realtime updates.

Comment: On a side note, if you have access to change the architecture of the app, consider [RethinkDB](https://www.rethinkdb.com/)

Comment: duuuuuuudeees you blowed my mind right now!!!!!!!! i think i'll study more about APIs for raspberry pi!!!! thanks